# EasyMock 3.1 InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

I am writing a test using easymock and junit that should be fairly simple. I have added functionality to an existing project, and I am testing that a method that I added works as expected. I can't post the detailed code (it's for work), but here is a version with the names changed:

```
public class ATest extends AbstractTestCase {
    private AFactory factory;
    private AServiceClient mockClient;
    private AServiceResult mockResult;
    private AnObject mockObject;
    private AnotherObject mockObject2;
    private Map<String, Object> mockMap;

    @Before
    public void setupMocks() {
        factory = new AFactory();
        mockClient = EasyMock.createMockBuilder(AServiceClient.class)
                .addMockedMethod("getAServiceResult")
                .createMock();
        factory.setClient(mockClient);
        mockResult = EasyMock.createMockBuilder(AServiceResult.class)
                .addMockedMethod("getAnObject")
                .createMock();
        mockObject = EasyMock.createMockBuilder(AnObject.class)
                .addMockedMethod("getAnotherObject")
                .createMock();
        mockObject2 = EasyMock.createMockBuilder(AnotherObject.class)
                .addMockedMethod("getMap")
                .createMock();

        mockMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        //Put a bunch of stuff in the map

        EasyMock.expect(mockObject2.getMap())
                .andReturn(mockMap)
                .once();
        EasyMock.expect(mockObject.getAnotherObject())
                .andReturn(mockObject2)
                .once();
        EasyMock.expect(mockResult.getAnObject())
                .andReturn(mockObject)
                .once();
    }

    @Test
    public void aTest throws SomeException {
        AnInstance inst = factory.getInstance();
        SomeInput input = SomeInput();
        //Populate input

        Set<String> expectedInnerInput = new HashSet<String>();
        //Populate expected inner input
        EasyMock.expect(mockClient.getAServiceResult(eq(expectedInnerInput), eq("1")))
                .andReturn(mockResult)
                .once();

        EasyMock.replay(mockClient, mockResult, mockObject, mockObject2);
        Map<SomeKey, Object> attrs = inst.getAttributes("a string", input);
        EasyMock.verify(mockClient, mockResult, mockObject, mockObject2);

        //A bunch of junit asserts on attrs
    }
}
```

(There may be typos in the above. Assume those mistakes came from me typing this here. My code was able to compile and run and it got all the way to the line between `EasyMock.replay` and `EasyMock.verify`.)

This is my stack trace (again with names changed):

```
[junit] Testcase: aTest(com.apackage.test.validation.ATest):    Caused an ERROR
[junit] java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
[junit] net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
[junit]     at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:237)
[junit]     at net.sf.cglib.reflect.FastClass$Generator.create(FastClass.java:64)
[junit]     at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.helper(MethodProxy.java:120)
[junit]     at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.init(MethodProxy.java:74)
[junit]     at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:213)
[junit]     at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory$MockMethodInterceptor.intercept(ClassProxyFactory.java:91)
[junit]     at com.apackage.aservice.client.AServiceClient$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$a9dce969.equals(<generated>)
[junit]     at org.easymock.internal.ExpectedInvocation.matches(ExpectedInvocation.java:85)
[junit]     at org.easymock.internal.UnorderedBehavior.addActual(UnorderedBehavior.java:57)
[junit]     at org.easymock.internal.MocksBehavior.addActual(MocksBehavior.java:87)
[junit]     at org.easymock.internal.ReplayState.invokeInner(ReplayState.java:58)
[junit]     at org.easymock.internal.ReplayState.invoke(ReplayState.java:46)
[junit]     at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:40)
[junit]     at org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:85)
[junit]     at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory$MockMethodInterceptor.intercept(ClassProxyFactory.java:94)
[junit]     at com.apackage.aservice.client.AServiceClient$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$a9dce969.getAServiceResult(<generated>)
[junit]     at com.apackage.validation.AnInstance.getAttributes(AnInstance.java:31)
[junit]     at com.apackage.test.validation.ATest.aTest(ATest.java:100)
[junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
[junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
[junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
[junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
[junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
[junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
[junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
[junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
[junit] Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[junit]     at net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:384)
[junit]     at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:219)
[junit] Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of  sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "$java/lang/Object$$FastClassByCGLIB$$3f697993"
[junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
[junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
```

Here are my constraints:

- I cannot use another version of EasyMock
- I cannot use another mock library
- I cannot not use mocks for this (obviously)

I've seen some things saying this is an EasyMock bug, but I would think that other people would have run into the same problem as me and updated to a newer version. I'm pretty sure there is something I'm doing wrong.

Comment: How are the mock dependencies making it onto the inst object? I can't see any constructor or setter calls that would imply the mocks make it to the inst object, either via the factory or directly. It would also be beneficial if we could see what you're trying to test (or at least a sample of it)

Comment: Oh, sorry. I forgot the line that adds the `mockClient` to the `factory`.

Basically, the factory passes the client onto a new instance of `AnInstance` and returns it. When `getAServiceResult` is called, it calls a backend service with the client, which is set to return the `mockResult`. `AServiceResult` contains a `AnObject`, which in turn contains a `AnotherObject`, which in turn contains a `Map`, so I had to mock those out too.

Comment: The code fails when it tries to call the mocked `getAServiceResult` on the client, which is the first mocked method that it reaches.

Comment: did you figure out the solution to this? I am running into the same issue.

Comment: It's a bug. Either upgrade to a newer version or use a different mocking library. I did the latter.